# Pronunciation Dictionary for Portuguese

Tags: pronunciation, phonemes, dictionary, portuguese

Is there any comprehensive pronunciation dictionary for Portoguese language like CMU dictionary for English?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how "comprehensive" it is, but the *Portal da Língua Portuguesa* has a [phonetic dictionary](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=fonetica&act=list&region=lbx) that seems to do a pretty good job. An interesting feature of it is that you can change the dialect, choosing among dialects from Portugal, Brazil, Africa and East Timor.